# How to Mask or Replace the values in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this **XML**:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TXLife xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" Version="2.22.00">

<TXLifeRequest>
 <OLifE Version="2.22.0">
  <Party id="BEB7-BDDC43FE3F01_10004">
   <PartyTypeCode tc="1">PT_PERSON</PartyTypeCode>
    <FullName>Gump,Forrest</FullName>
    <ResidenceState tc="58">USA_WI</ResidenceState>
    <Person id="D7329BB530E8_10304">
     <FirstName>Forrest</FirstName>
     <LastName>Gump</LastName>
    </Person>
  </Party>
 </OLifE>
</TXLifeRequest>
</TXLife>
```

I want Replace the `FirstName` value to `No Name`.

This is related to Data Masking.

I'm trying to access the node with the given code below, but it is not working.

```
var testXML = XDocument.Load("C:\\DataMask\\P0500015703691806181259345440127.xml");
            var nodePTCode = testXML.Descendants("Party").FirstOrDefault(cd => cd.Element("PartyTypeCode").Value == "PT_PERSON");
```

Comment: You're missing namespaces. All these nodes are in the `http://ACORD...` namespace. Look at `XNamespace`.

Comment: How can I add this code?

Answer (score 1):

The **namespace** has to be included when addressing the elements.
Also for an `XDocument` you have to start from its **`Root`** property.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\DataMask\\P0500015703691806181259345440127.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2";
XElement firstName = xdoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "FirstName").FirstOrDefault();
if (firstName != null) { firstName.Value = "No Name"; }
```

The xml will have the update applied:

```
<TXLife xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" Version="2.22.00">
    <TXLifeRequest>
        <OLifE Version="2.22.0">
            <Party id="BEB7-BDDC43FE3F01_10004">
                <PartyTypeCode tc="1">PT_PERSON</PartyTypeCode>
                <FullName>Gump,Forrest</FullName>
                <ResidenceState tc="58">USA_WI</ResidenceState>
                <Person id="D7329BB530E8_10304">
                    <FirstName>No Name</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Gump</LastName>
                </Person>
            </Party>
        </OLifE>
    </TXLifeRequest>
</TXLife>
```

**Edit**

If applicable, you'll also have to update the `FullName` xml element to reflect the change in `FirstName`.

```
XElement lastName = xdoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "LastName").FirstOrDefault();
XElement fullName = xdoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "FullName").FirstOrDefault();
fullName.Value = String.Format("{0},{1}", (String)lastName, (String)firstName);
```

Comment: Thanks Man, I am replacing so many values in XML in Party node. Here I have givven only very small sample XML.